# Typescript infinite recursion reasoning

Tags: typescript

Check this typescript 4.2 snippet I found somewhere (playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgNgQwMYGsCyCDmBLJAeAFQD4oBeKAbygG0BpKbAOyhQhAHsAzKAgXQC5YiVBhz4CdXiQC+AWABQCgCYQkiAE7Qk7RgGdgUTu3aD4ydFlx4KAR0H71TTNKIBuZao1ad+qA9PCFmJ4Dk5uHmoImlDaegaMAK4AtgHmolYAjABM4fJAA)):

```js
type BlackMagic<T> = { [K in keyof T]: BlackMagic<T[K]> }

declare const foo: BlackMagic<{q: string}>;
declare const str: BlackMagic<string>;
declare const num: BlackMagic<12>;
```

I can't wrap my head around it. How does TS handle this? How is it not stuck in an infinite recursion? Specifically, in the case of `str` and `num`, hovering over the variables shows that TS is resolving the types to just `string` and `12`. How's that even happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would get stuck in an infinite recursion if your type included `BlackMagic<T>` *with the same `T`*, but here we are applying the utility type `BlackMagic` to a different value `T[K]`.

```
type BlackMagic<T> = { [K in keyof T]: BlackMagic<T[K]> }
```

This type says that `BlackMagic<T>` is an `object` where the keys are the keys of `T` and the values are a `BlackMagic` mapped version of the values of `T`.

---

The `BlackMagic` type doesn't actually do anything in your examples your examples `str` and `num`.

If `T` is a primitive type instead of an `object` then `BlackMagic<T>` is just `T` itself.  This is the standard behavior for [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) which are [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  For example `Partial<12>` is just `12`.  This behavior is explained in the FAQ [Common "Bugs" That Aren't Bugs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#common-bugs-that-arent-bugs)

> Mapped types declared as `{ [ K in keyof T ]: U }` where `T` is a type parameter are known as homomorphic mapped types, which means that the mapped type is a structure preserving function of `T`. When type parameter `T` is instantiated with a primitive type the mapped type evaluates to the same primitive.

---

`foo: BlackMagic<{q: string}>` will actually do some mapping, but it's only one level deep.  `BlackMagic<{q: string}>` becomes `{q: BlackMagic<string>}`.  We just saw that `BlackMagic<string>` is `string`, so the type next becomes `{q: string}`.

Answer (score 3):

As Linda explains, the reason why there's no infinite recursion is that when a homomorphic mapped type is applied to a primitive type it evaluates to that primitive type. Still, it's interesting to see what happens with a non-homomorphic mapped type. To define a non-homomorphic type, you can declare an identity type `I` such that `I<'key1' | 'key2'> = 'key1' | 'key2'`, using a conditional type:

```
type I<T> = T extends infer S ? S : T
```

By taking the keys from `I<keyof T>` instead of `keyof T`, you can define a simple non-recursive and non-homomorphic type:

```
type NonHomomorphicMap<T> = {[K in I<keyof T>]: 42}
```

and apply it to a bunch of other types:

```
type TestObject = NonHomomorphicMap<{q: string}> // {q: 42}
type TestString = NonHomomorphicMap<string>      // {[x: number]: 42, toString: 42, charAt: 42, ...}
type TestNum = NonHomomorphicMap<12>             // {toString: 42, toFixed: 42, toExponential: 42, toPrecision: 42, valueOf: 42, toLocaleString: 42}
type TestFun = NonHomomorphicMap<() => number>   // {}
```

For `string` and `12` the type now evaluates to an object type with keys for all the methods on `string` and `number`, and an `[x: number]` index signature for `string`.

Interestingly, functions are not treated as primitive types, but as objects without keys, so `NonHomomorphicMap<() => any>` equals `{}`. This also happens with homomorphic mapped types (i.e. `BlackMagic<() => any>` equals `{}`), so `BlackMagic` is not identity.

It's also possible to make a recursive non-homomorphic type similar to `BlackMagic`, but to see the full type on hover you need a `Normalize` type that fully evaluates all recursive occurrences:

```
type Normalize<T> =
  T extends Function
  ? T
  : T extends infer S ? {[K in keyof S]: S[K]} : never
```

Now a non-homomorphic `BlackMagic` counterpart can be defined as:

```
type BadMagic<T> = Normalize<{
    [K in I<keyof T>]: K extends keyof T ? BadMagic<T[K]> : never
}>
```

Besides using `Normalize` and `I`, there's also an extra conditional `K extends keyof T` as TypeScript can't infer that the result of applying `I` can still index `T`. This does not affect the behavior though.

Applying `BadMagic` to the sample types yields

```
type TestObject = BadMagic<{q: string}> // {q: {[x: number]: {[x: number]: BadMagic<string>,...}, toString: {}, charAt: {}, ...}}
type TestString = BadMagic<string>      // {[x: number]: {[x: number]: {[x: number]: BadMagic<string>, ...}, toString: {}, charAt: {}, ...}, toString: {}, charAt: {}, ...}
type TestNum = BadMagic<12>             // {toString: {}, toFixed: {}, toExponential: {}, toPrecision: {}, valueOf: {}, toLocaleString: {}}
type TestFun = BadMagic<() => any>      // {}
```

Most of the recursion ends at methods that turn into `{}`, but if you look at `BadMagic<string>` you can see there is in fact some "infinite" recursion, as the `[x: number]` property on strings is itself a string. Basically, you have

```
BadMagic<string> = {
  [x: number]: {
    [x: number]: {
      [x: number]: BadMagic<string>, // "infinite"
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  toString: {},
  charAt: {},
  ...
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gJwLYEMA2BLAXhAPAFQD4oBeAWACgop8oIAPYCAOwBMBnKAMQFdmBjYBjjNK1APw0xUAFw06jFhygZmAMwgIoAZSiSA3gG0A0iuZQA1hBBw1OgLpztJ%20wF9ZUZhABumypVBIKABJAmISeQYmNk5VDS1dSV05WgB6VJDcAHIrEABGLKgAHygc6wAmLPDS3ILimoqs-wpA6AAhNBR%20CwBZFABzDH4w0lhEVEwcXH0oEzNLa1saRxoXKFdCZv1palaaCHZgAHkAIwArCEFRjq7egaHpgEc5Q4RVfo2odKh9Z6hX96uHZQPb4A7AbTAN7MfrXTrdPqDYYAmHEajo74o-rA0HgmA8JBw26Ih55cpo9GUynfMk48DQMGHXjmCI3BH3YYACgAlKRiChmCAKdRvvogRRxQF6WNmAAJOBIBWIMAACyGfTAIwiRlMqkyuSWRBWABZypKKNsqOjcYdThcrhF4HKlYqEKr1ShNb8XlDAcRRX9TeLKTaIb6YaMnfLFa73fwNbgscKRRkjPQ5MwCSdNCbygAaEFwSHQ-pyU0F-gqlAIACCwDL%20agADoW8HrdLGcB8YTHSJo0q3Wr457cGTk1SMangEXw6WoOXC1wMPQIKwGwXpwBRehgEQsITodeFgAKCEuGHYwmYR%2086B4ECOaiP04AMnB%20OgIMX3g227sO%20CzKRn2LrKkOCY8nyUACkKE6iuK5p7G0KCsCSwxEMByDoNgeCWpScx6qEBp2EachrFESicIYxHLHoUDIahHIEC4xAZj4fgSpsFCUHh7ZBJ2dqXMA1woWhTw%20iWnwBnIaYZlmOYyYY6aePJCArAxYlJnmLZNq4G4ziWMl6VAlbVnWRkFjprh-iCAGHN%20EasqJTFJnBqZKXJSDZmpinKZmXkKT8HkqQFPn0c5SKJrOhCWa2%20kOXOYoVlWtb1j8xlWfFs4WSZKXmelsW6XS-F4gSImMZFY4TtVorTglOXTkuK5rgVhbbruXjMAeaANXAp7npeIg5beaD3o%20vVvh%20aBftl6U2aGQFORVDyQSQ-KCuO8GUOKQA)